# nuSoap Function is Not a Valid method

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, nusoap

When trying to instantiate my `nuSoap` method `authenticateUser`, it says:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] Function ("authenticateUser") is not a valid method for this service in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/projo/dev/home.php:14

But when I replace that method name for one that already works, everything works just fine. So I think the instantiation syntax isn't wrong.

```
/*-----------
Authenticate User
------------*/
$server->register(
    // method name
    'authenticateUser',

    // input parameters
    array('sessionUserName' => 'xsd:string', 'sessionHash' => 'xsd:string', 'user' => 'xsd:string', 'pass' => 'xsd:string'),        

    // output parameters
    array('return' => 'xsd:string'),

    // namespace
    $namespace,

    // soapaction
    $namespace . '#authenticateUser',

    // style
    'rpc',

    // use
    'encoded',

    // documentation
    'authenticates a user and returns a json array of the user info'
);

function authenticateUser($sessionUserName, $sessionHash, $user, $pass)
{
    //Check to see if a countryCode was provided
    if ($sessionUserName != '' && $sessionHash != '' && $user == $GLOBALS['wsUser'] && $pass == $GLOBALS['wsPass'])
    {

        $suid = 'AUTH'.$GLOBALS['guid'].'SESSION';


        $database   = new SQLDatabase();
        $database->openConnection();
        $database->selectDb();

        //Query
        $sql    = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE member_email='" . $sessionUserName . "' LIMIT 1";

        //Query MySQL
        $return = $database->query($sql);
        $userDetails = $database->fetch_array( $return );



        if(!empty($userDetails)) {
            $userDetails[0]['authSession'] = $suid;
            $newArr = $userDetails[0];
            $response = json_encode($newArr);
        }

        /*print $sql.'<br /><pre>';
        print_r($response);
        echo '</pre>';*/

        //Throw SQL Errors
        if (!mysql_query($sql))
        {
                die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        //Return on Success
        return $response;   

        //Close Connection
        mysql_close($con);
    }
    else
    {
        return 'Error: You must supply all of the inputs!x';
    }
}
```

There are two things I can think of that would cause this error:

1. More likely: my registration of the function is somehow incorrect, even though the **wsdl gui** shows that the function is registered correctly and I've been able to successfully consume the method via the `SoapUI` program.
2. Less likely: somehow, the function isn't broken anymore, but its cached and so I'm seeing an old error.

**The Question**: When trying to consume this  `soap` service method via `PHP`, why do I get an output error stating that this function doesn't exist in the service, when it clearly is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set

```
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
```

In every file you use soap from, or set `wsdl_cache_enabled`
to `0` in your `php.ini` file.

```
[soap]
; Enables or disables WSDL caching feature.
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled=0
```

Comment: thanks! I've been wanting to figure out how to cancel the caching.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Linux, you can also directly delete the cached wsdl file from /tmp/ dir

Answer (score 1):

**It was the CACHE**!!! stupid. All I had to do was close my computer and go to bed. When I woke up, I ran the file again and it worked like a charm.

This is the second time this has happened with a function in a SOAP service.

Now I need to know how to clear the cache of a soap service. (nuSoap)